# Find specific file in folder and edit it

Tags: c

I am really new to C, so maybe the question is too easy or not relevant. But I didn't find answer to this question.

I have folder with files which named as: -90.txt, -89.txt, ..., 0.txt, 1.txt, 2.txt, ..., 90.txt.

I need to have some function which will receive number (folder name) as an argument and open that file.

```
function editFile(number){
    fp=fopen("/data/" + number + ".txt", "wr");

    ...
    // do some other things
}
```

Comment: In C you cannot build a string in that way. Use `sprintf` to create the file name in a local variable.

Comment: I know I can't. That's kind of pseudo code which shows what actually I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C you do not have flexibility to add a number to a string. If you want to append a number to a string then first you have to convert it into a string using [`itoa`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/) function. You can find online documentation about that function.

And here is general outline how would you add a number to string in C

- First convert the number into string (store it in a new buffer of type `char[]`) using `itoa` or [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/)
- Then make a new buffer of type `char[]`. Make sure you create it of enough size so that it can hold complete file path.
- Then use [`strcat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat) to append the two strings.

Instead of all the above process, you can also use `sprintf`.

- Then you can pass the result to [`fopen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting edit. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`C` doesn't have strings with the idea of concatenation. So if you want to concatenate strings you have to use functions like this:

```
function editFile(char* number)
{
    char pathName[MAX_PATH];
    strcpy(pathName, "/data/");
    strcat(pathName, number);
    strcat(pathName, ".txt");
    fp=fopen(pathName, "wr");

    ...
    // do some other things
}
```

You can utilize `sprintf` to make it shorter. But you should add security checks because you have the risk of buffer overrun. Hint: `strcpy_s`, `strccat_s`, `sprintf_s`. (But this' beyond the answer to your question.)

Answer (score 1):

In C you cannot build a string in that way. Use `sprintf` to create the file name in a local variable.

```
char filename[1024];
sprintf(filename, "/data/%d.txt", number); // assume that a signed value comes from `int`
fp = fopen(filename, "w+");                // replaced "wr"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably used to high level languages where you can "build" a string by concatenating integers, floats, other strings, etc. to it.  This doesn't work in C.

The [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) function is the right tool for the job:

```
char buffer[PATH_MAX]; // assuming POSIX
snprintf(buffer, PATH_MAX, "/data/%d.txt", number);
fp = fopen(buffer, "wr");
```